# How to list all xlinks in Plastic repo

Tags: list, repository, plasticscm, xlink

I have Plastic SCM version 9 windows client and I want to list all xlinks inside repo (incl subdirs). I know this is impossible in graphical mode. However I was thinking I could list all dirs with subdirs to file (using command line) and then parse it with `cm xlink -s`.

I'm stuck at this point. I tried following dos command:

`for %%x in (dirlist.txt) do cm xlink -s %%x`

but it checks only dirlist.txt file. What is the correct dos command to do this?
**dirlist.txt** looks like this:

```
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir1\subdir1
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir1\subdir2
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir2
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir2\subdir1
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir2\subdir2
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir3
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir3\subdir1
c:\users\xxx\plastic\some_repo\dir3\subdir2
```

...and so on. Basically I need to check every subdir from within dirlist.txt if it's an xlink or not. If it's not then the command will return message *some_dir is not an xlink.* but if it encounter xlink then it will show proper message.

Or maybe there is another quicker way to do this?

Comment: The commando "cm fileinfo --help" is helpful to determine if an item is an Xlink. With the command "cm ls --help" you can list the content of a changeset/workspace tree and the output includes information of the items if it's an Xlink or not.

Comment: Thanks. For now I've managed to answer myself. The correct command is ```for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (dirlist.txt) do cm xlink -s %%x```. However I will look into your answer as well. Thanks again!